# Using "in" operator in where clause of entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, razor

i want all products to be available under current category including all child categories.
my code is something like this :

```
int[] toCheck =new int[2];

toCheck[0] = 1;
toCheck[1] = 2;
toCheck[2] = 3;

var products = db.Products.Include(x => x.categoryByProductID).Where(x => x.CategoryID in ?);
```

here `categoryByProductID` = all child categories,
     `?` = how can i use `toCheck[]` array

or any other solution to check `CategoryID` with predefined values !!!

any help appreciable ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at it slightly the other way up- does the list of categories contain the category of this product?

```
var products = db.Products.Include(x => x.categoryByProductID).Where(x => toCheck.Contains(x.CategoryID));
```

Comment: Contains works in .NET 4.0 but not in 3.5 SP1 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
var products = db.Products.Include(x => x.categoryByProductID).Where(x => toCheck.Any(y => y == x.CategoryID));
```